# how to prevent hashmap or treemap from replacing the previous value

Tags: java

how can I prevent hashmap or treemap from replacing the previous key value if already present?Also,I want to throw an exception to notify the user.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any such map would be violating the normal `Map` interface, to be honest. But if you're happy to do that, you could easily create your own `Map` implementation which delegates to another map, but only after checking for the presence of an existing element:

```
public final class NonReplacementMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {
    private final Map<K, V> original;

    public NonReplacementMap(Map<K, V> original) {
        this.original = original;
    }

    @Override
    public void put(K key, V value) {
        if (original.containsKey(key)) {
            // Or whatever unchecked exception you want
            throw new IllegalStateException("Key already in map");
        }
        original.put(key, value);
    }

    // etc
}
```

Comment: could you please tell me how it is violating the map inerface.

Comment: It's right there [in the docs](http://bit.ly/17HOd9G): `If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.`

Answer (score 7):

Use myMap.putIfAbsent(key, val)

This has been introduced in the Map interface since 1.8

```
     * @since 1.8
     */
     default V putIfAbsent(K key, V value) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just wrap your map? [Composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

```
void put(Object key, Object value){
    if(map.containsKey(key)){
     throw Exception("Custom exception");
    }else{
    map.put(key,value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Map#containsKey(object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) method to check if key is there already before adding it to the `Map`

Answer (score 0):

No,by default you cannot,because it seems specific requirement for you.

So create your own class which extends `HashMap`/any implementation and ovveride  inserting methods .

If key matches with existing one `return` from there/`throw` some `exception`.